# How to select font for burning subtitles with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

When burning subtitles into video with ffmpeg and libass, the Arial font is selected by default. How do I choose a **font** and **font size** manually? I googled this to no avail. (I'm on OS X if it matters.)

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-libass
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt out.avi

ffmpeg version 2.8.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fc161421ac0] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.1.2 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fc161421ac0] Using font provider coretext
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fc161421ac0] fontselect: (Arial, 400, 0) -> /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf, -1, ArialMT
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [`subtitles` filter options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#subtitles-1).

Use the `force_style` option with a font name passed to the ASS `FontName` parameter to force a different font:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='FontName=DejaVu Serif' out.avi
```

You may need to specify a font path with the `fontsdir` option. This applies if your fonts provider (`coretext` in your case) does not include the path where your font is installed.